# Periodo ipotetico della semi-irrealtà

Tags: grammar

Come posso dire al meglio questo concetto?
Questa frase mi sembra sbagliata e cacofonica, soprattutto nell'uso del verbo "dovere" ma non riesco a trovare di meglio...

*"Non avendo trovato errori, non dovremmo esserci persi informazioni."*

La formula:

*"Non ho trovato errori quindi non ci siamo persi informazioni."*

Non va bene perché per me è importante lasciare un velo di possibilità sebbene sia una possibilità pressoché irreale.

Comment: La domanda è molto interessante, ma c'entra poco il concetto di “periodo ipotetico”, che si riferisce specificamente a quelle frasi con un'ipotesi (“se X”) e la sua conseguenza (“allora Y”). Certo, anche nella tua c'è qualcosa del genere fra le righe, ma così com'è non è un periodo ipotetico.

Comment: Grazie @DaG, sinceramente non sapevo che nome dare a questa costruzione... precisiamo infatti che i periodi ipotetici reali o futuri, possono essere introdotti solo da "se" e quelli possibili e irreali anche da "qualora" o "a patto che". In questo caso però parliamo di un periodo ipotetico praticamente sottointeso (molto improbabile ma non irreale) : "SE non abbiamo trovato errori, non dovremmo esserci persi informazioni"... quindi per me la frase è assimilabile come periodo ipotetico